# Android Studio Arctic Fox (Adb) - Connected Devices are being disconnected after some time

Tags: android, adb, android-studio-arctic-fox

I have 7 different Android phones which all have different Android OS. All of them are facing the same disconnection problem. Devices are being disconnected approx after an hour later. When it's disconnected, `Allow USB debugging?` pop-up appears **twice** and wants me to Allow the computer's RSA key fingerprint which was already approved. Also, under `Connection Assistant`, the connected device turns into `disconnected` state by Android Studio but adb reports it's in `device` state.

Sometimes I can re-connect the device only if I click different USB Preferences. But it disconnects after some time later again.

I tried so many solutions to fix the device connection problem. I used to fix it usually with one of the solutions below. Unfortunately, the problem keeps persisting. I've never faced something like this before.

What I tried:

- Unplug and replug the USB cable. (tried different cables)
- Disable then enable USB debugging in the device settings.
- Tried different USB type-C ports
- Rebooting Devices
- Rebooting Android Studio and MacBook
- open `.android` and delete file named as `adbkey` and `adbkey.pub`
- `adb kill-server` then `adb start-server`
- Revoking USB debugging authorizations
- Removed `Android/sdk/build-tools` and `Android/sdk/platform-tools` and reinstalled again.
- Updated `bash_profile` like in below:

```
export ANDROID_HOME=/Users/myMacBook/Library/Android/sdk
export PATH=$PATH:$ANDROID_HOME/emulator
export PATH=$PATH:$ANDROID_HOME/tools
export PATH=$PATH:$ANDROID_HOME/tools/bin
export PATH=$PATH:$ANDROID_HOME/platform-tools
```

I really don't want to remove Android Studio and re-install it. I hope someone can help me. Thanks in advance!

Versions:

- Android Debug Bridge version 1.0.41
- Version 31.0.3-7562133

```
Android Studio Arctic Fox | 2020.3.1 Patch 3
Build #AI-203.7717.56.2031.7784292, built on October 1, 2021
Runtime version: 11.0.10+0-b96-7281165 x86_64
VM: OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM by JetBrains s.r.o.
macOS 11.6
GC: G1 Young Generation, G1 Old Generation
Memory: 3072M
Cores: 8
Registry: external.system.auto.import.disabled=true
Non-Bundled Plugins: org.jetbrains.kotlin
```

Screenshots:
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's fixed after I updated my macBook to macOS Monterey.

EDIT:

I found the real reason why devices are being disconnected.
If you try to inspect a webView in Chrome (chrome://inspect/#devices), Studio disconnects the connection of your devices after sometime

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/57397907/4074312

Comment: Ran into this as well.  They seem to work together as long as you uncheck "Discover USB devices" in Chrome.  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61591205/physical-devices-not-working-in-android-studio-multiple-rsa-key-fingerprints-bu

Answer (score 0):

This issue has sprung up again in the latest version of Android Studio due to having mDNS enabled, [please see here for the thread on how to solve it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70936120/android-studio-disconnects-from-physical-device).