# Android Studio Disconnects From Physical Device

Tags: android, android-studio, google-chrome, debugging, adb

[Android Studio Bumblebee (2021.1.1)](https://android-developers.googleblog.com/2022/01/android-studio-bumblebee-202111-stable.html) was released stably on 25 January 2022 bundled with a new Device Manager (accompanying new support for Android 11+ device debugging over WIFI). I jumped on this stable release, updating from [Android Studio Arctic Fox (2020.3.1 Patch 4)](https://androidstudio.googleblog.com/2021/12/android-studio-arctic-fox-202031-patch.html).

Unfortunately however, since updating, physical devices/handsets don't remain connected to Android Studio for the purpose of debugging. I can confirm that the issue was introduced from **Android Studio Bumblebee** onwards (occurring in **Beta** and **Canary** builds also). I've reproduced the issue on Android Studio **Bumblebee** (Stable), **Chipmunk** (Beta), and **Dolphin** (Canary), but **Android Studio Arctic Fox** (superseded Stable) continues to work just fine.

The issue occurs soon after opening Android Studio (**Bumblebee+**) with one of my physical devices connected. Everything appears fine initially and I may even have enough time to deploy my project to the handset, before the device disappears from Android Studio (as if I'd physically disconnected the USB cable from my computer or from the handset itself).

I've tried a fair few things in an attempt to determine a root cause. These include testing:

- With different USB cables.
- With different handsets (both varying makes and models).
- With various versions of the Android Studio IDE (as mentioned above).
- Plugging the USB cables into different USB ports on my computer.
- Rebooting handsets and my computer.
- Restarting Android Studio.
- Invalidating caches and restarting Android Studio.
- `adb kill-server` then `adb start-server`.
- Revoking/reaccepting USB debugging authorization.
- Reinstalled build tools/platform tools, and ADB.
- A great number of further possibilities, to no avail.

I searched and read through remotely similar issues, including (but not limited to) these:

- [Android Studio Arctic Fox (Adb) - Connected Devices are being disconnected after some time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69823477/android-studio-arctic-fox-adb-connected-devices-are-being-disconnected-after)
- [Android debugger continually disconnects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19434797/android-debugger-continually-disconnects)

[This particular comment](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57397907/5692877) in one of the above issues clued me onto a possible root cause:

> I have been fighting for a few days with adb not seeing my device. After trying many other posted solutions, I discovered that the issue was with Chrome also trying to connect its debugger to a web view. If Chrome is connected using chrome://inspect, then adb seems to disconnect. Quitting Chrome resolves the issue. Then I can connect with Android Studio and then restart Chrome and reconnect. Hope this helps someone else.

However I've been unable to do anything with the above discovery, other than close Google Chrome, and hope for the best. Obviously this isn't an ideal solution. **It appears as though the moment Google Chrome shows the connected physical device in the [chrome://inspect/#devices](http://chrome://inspect/#devices) page, the physical device promptly becomes unavailable through Android Studio.**

I've jumped back to **Android Studio Arctic Fox** (2020.3.1 Patch 4) for the moment, however this brings with it other issues (my current core project targets the latest SDK version, which requires the updated IDE).

Absolutely any help with this would be insanely appreciated. I've exhausted just about every avenue that I can think of!

Comment: Did you report it at https://issuetracker.google.com/issues?q=componentid:192708&s=modified_time:descfirst&pli=1 (*adding the valuable info you provided here*)

Comment: Not sure if this is yours or not: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/217251994 You may want to add which version of Google Chrome you used and if not attempt to inspect/#devices made it stable-ish or not.

Comment: Found this report: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/216856179 which suggested `downgrading platform-tools from the last version to 28.0.0`

Comment: @DiegoTorresMilano I hadn't yet reported it there, though I've located a remotely similar ticket (found by @morrison-chang) and shall add my notes to that. [SouthbayDev's answer below](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70944942/5692877) did the trick for working around the issue and may assist Android Studio devs in remedying the root cause. I might also mention that I didn't test downgrading `platform-tools` due to the aforementioned answer successfully working around the issue.

Answer (score 71, accepted):

I solved the problem by disabling

Settings -> Build, Execution, Deployment -> Debugger -> "Enable adb mDNS for wireless debugging"

[image: adb mDNS settings screenshot]

Comment: Unbelievable! This did the trick for me also. I found that after disabling this setting, I had to re-connect my handset to the computer, but after that, it remained stably connected and available through Android Studio from then on! You've saved me a hell of a lot of further digging @SouthbayDev, so thanks again.

Comment: You're welcome!  :-)

Comment: It was actually the first setting that I tried, because one of the main new features in BumbleBee is the over-the-air debugging. This is also the solution for similar problems with the emulator.

Comment: I couldn't find this option, can u please add a screen shot?

Comment: The problem should be solved with the current version of AndroidStudio!

Comment: Damn i was working for month by unpluging and pluging the device again and you finally solved it.

Comment: Still had this problem. Your answer saved me! Ive been pulling my hear out for days

Comment: This resolved the issue for me on electric eel

Comment: Still facing the problem.

Comment: disabling this results in android studio not being able to generate the QR to pair

Comment: Still same for me! Android Studio Flamingo | 2022.2.1 Patch 2

Comment: makes no difference for me, had problems for years, with many different cables and phones, wasted a dreadful amount of time

Comment: The QR code never worked anyway

Answer (score 6):

I'm developing for android for almost 10 years now and I'm struggling with this annoying issue regularly - while debugging with android studio and a physicals device the device suddenly disconnect with no apparent reason.
sometime it gets into a loop of disconnect/reconnect for a few times

During the years I change PC, Devices, cables - but always at some point the problem persist.

I think there are many reason for this problem, including:

- Bad/old cables
- Erosion of the USB socket of the PC or the device
- bugs in ADB/Android Studio/Android device

I tried to work with WIFI plugging, most of them didn't work, the one who did work, solve the issue, but were ridiculously slow

I search the web many times and couldn't find an answer that solve the issue for me, partly because there are many different reason for this, which makes each answer very specific.

Therefore I suggest that if any body find a solution for his specific case, please add it as an answer here for the the benefit of other.

Currently I found the following solution: after I bought many cables, I was finally able to find one that doesn't disconnect as much (I actually borrowed it from my work...)

AND I also use Vysor, which project the android screen to my PC, so that I don't have to move or touch the Physically device, which reduce the problem to almost never.

I also noticed that it happens more when the battery is 100% so I try to keep it below

Comment: The stopgap solution that seems to work for everyone is the one provided by @SouthbayDev - https://stackoverflow.com/a/70944942/5692877  hopefully it works for you also (I believe it will given that your difficulties sound similar to my own at the time of authoring the original post. 

Comment: Which company cable you brought, can you provide Amazon link ?

Answer (score 1):

I had this problem just now because im just getting into Android development, noticed my problem was that i was using a type c to type c cable, i switched to a usb to type c cable and it worked. i have to mention this is also in my SS USB port so idk if that made a difference. but if this helps anyone im glad

Comment: Thanks, this trick solved my problem. I am using a multiport adapter for my Mac and connected a Type-C to Type-C cable from the adapter to my mobile. This was causing the issue of connecting and disconnecting continuously, so when I removed the multiport adapter and connected my Type-C cable directly to my laptop, it worked.

Answer (score 0):

For me only after disabling both

- Use libusb backend and
- Enable adb mDNS for wireless debugging worked.

[image]

Comment: The `Use libuse backend` is unchecked by default, is that right?

Answer (score -3):

SOLVED this with changing usb on pc from USB 3.0 port (blue type) to USB 2.0