# Weird adb logs, I get a lot of these logs

Tags: android, flutter, dart

who can please explain what it is? I use adb

`W/IMGMapper(21885): set:488 set: Unset optional value from type CTA861_3 W/IMGMapper(21885): set:488 set: Unset optional value from type SMPTE2094_40`

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: yor need to run android app over wifi in android studio?

Comment: It seems some android source code files like [this file](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/av/+/master/media/codec2/sfplugin/Codec2Buffer.cpp) or [this one](https://cs.android.com/android/platform/superproject/+/master:out/soong/.intermediates/hardware/interfaces/graphics/mapper/4.0/android.hardware.graphics.mapper@4.0_genc++_headers/gen/android/hardware/graphics/mapper/4.0/IMapper.h;l=468;drc=85468a34f119e699f604718701d2ff8721d3105c) contain the types mentioned in the warning messages `SMPTE2094_40 SMPTE2086 CTA861_3`. However, I don't know why nor how to get rid of them.

Comment: Using Xamarin Android I'm seeing these messages in my output window as well. Would love to get rit of it, because it really happens a lot.

Comment: I have a similar issue with Android jetpack compose. Didn't notice it in the logs before but recently it's all over and spamming

Comment: Similar issue here with my cordova app... i get same 3 messages over and over
IMGMapper     W  set:488 set: Unset optional value from type SMPTE2086, * CTA861_3, * SMPTE2094_40

Answer (score 4):

I have a workaround.

If you are working in Android Studio, you can fight back against this message from spamming your console by doing the following.

When the app is launched and you see these three messages spamming, right click on one of the messages, and click **Fold Lines Like This**.
[image: Screenshot of console showing a context menu open with a highlighted option for 'fold lines like this'.]

You will be prompted to add a new rule for folding console lines. Accept the new rule by clicking **OK**.
[image: Screenshot of Android Studio window open for adding a new console fold rule.]

After repeating this for the following two IMGMapper lines, your console will look much better!
[image: Screenshot of Android Studio window open with all three console fold rules in place.]

I know it's not a real solution. But if this issue is still haunting you, this workaround may help. I figure other IDEs must also have filtering options for the console as well.

Answer (score 1):

My workaround is to right-click on my app's tag and specifically add it to the filter so everything else is filtered out. Still not a solution though.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

A solution whilst in the midst of another problem presented itself.

Disable the following setting:
Settings -> Build, Execution, Deployment -> Debugger -> "Enable adb mDNS for wireless debugging"

I no longer have those log items and also my device does not disconnect, all my problems solved with one tickbox.

more information in: [Android Studio Disconnects From Physical Device](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70936120/android-studio-disconnects-from-physical-device/70944942#70944942)